# How to remove contour's clabel

Tags: python, matplotlib, counter

As we know that we can remove the collections of contour/contourf. But how can I remove the contour's clabel?

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplots(111)
for ivalue in range(10):
    values = alldata [ivalue,:,:]
    cs = plt.contour(x,y,vakues)
    cb = plt.clabel(cs, cs.levels)
     # now remove cs
    for c in cs.collections:
        c.remove()
    # but how can I remove cb?
    plt.savefig('%s.png'%ivalue)
```

The clabel of  first png still exists in second png. So i want to remove clabel meanwhile.

Comment: Don't call `clabel()`?

Comment: Sorry, I should give some scripts.

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't get your question: *"but how can I remove cb?"*. Why try to remove it, when your problem is solved when you don't call `clabel`?

Comment: Might be good to post the *actual* problem, i.e. how do you end up with a contour plot with labels, which you can't remove by not callling `clabel()`, or clarify why you first want to add labels, only to remove them later.

Comment: @Bart I just want to plot figure quickly. Create one figure and a
it's axis --- plot contour and clabel --- savefig . So after plot contour i need to remove it and it's clabel. That's why i want to remove clabel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the exact same as you are already doing for the `contour` lines. Minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

pl.figure()
for i in range(2):
    c  = pl.contour(np.random.random(100).reshape(10,10))
    cl = pl.clabel(c)

    if i == 1:
        pl.savefig('fig.png'.format(i))
```

Results in double contours, labels:

[image]

By changing it to:

```
    # Same code as above left out

    if i == 1:
        pl.savefig('fig.png'.format(i))

    for contour in c.collections:
        contour.remove()

    for label in cl:
        label.remove()
```

[image]