# How to put contour labels as legend in a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I am plotting contours, using an example from this link (code and output plot below) https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/matplotlib-pyplot-contour-in-python/

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib
   
delta = 0.15
x = np.arange(1.5, 2.5, delta)
y = np.arange(1.0, 3.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = (np.exp(X - Y))
  
  
CS1 = plt.contour(X, Y, Z)
   
fmt = {}
strs = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
for l, s in zip(CS1.levels, strs):
    fmt[l] = s
plt.clabel(CS1, CS1.levels, inline = True,
           fmt = fmt, fontsize = 10)
  
plt.title('matplotlib.pyplot.contour() Example')
plt.show()
```

The output is:
[image]

I want the labels for each contour as a legend in the corner, not along the contour lines. Is there a way?

Comment: The legend is created with the following content when referenced from the [reference](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/contour_api.html). `handles, lables = CS1.legend_elements('y');plt.legend(handles, lables, loc='upper right')`

Answer (score 1):

1. This post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490302/how-do-you-create-a-legend-for-a-contour-plot-in-matplotlib) shows a couple of ways to create a legend for your contours. Specifically, you can use

```py
for i in range(len(cl)): 
  CS1.collections[i].set_label(cl[i].get_text())
```

to create a custom legend for your contours.

2. To remove the labels from the contours inside the plot, you can use the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47049296/matplotlib-how-to-remove-contours-clabel). It consists in iteratively removing the labels with `label.remove()`

Below is what the final code looks like:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib
   
delta = 0.15
x = np.arange(1.5, 2.5, delta)
y = np.arange(1.0, 3.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = (np.exp(X - Y))
  
  
CS1 = plt.contour(X, Y, Z)

fmt = {}

strs = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
for l, s in zip(CS1.levels, strs):
    fmt[l] = s

cl=plt.clabel(CS1, CS1.levels,fmt=fmt, inline = False, fontsize = 10)

plt.title('matplotlib.pyplot.contour() Example')
for i in range(len(cl)): 
  CS1.collections[i].set_label(cl[i].get_text())


for label in cl:
  label.remove()

plt.legend()
```

And the output gives:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
delta = 0.15
x = np.arange(1.5, 2.5, delta)
y = np.arange(1.0, 3.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = (np.exp(X - Y))
  
CS1 = plt.contour(X, Y, Z)
   
nm, lbl = CS1.legend_elements()
lbl_ = [i for i in range(1, len(lbl))]
plt.legend(nm, lbl_) 

plt.title('matplotlib.pyplot.contour() Example')
plt.show()
```

[image]